# Saving the value of UISlider

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I've managed to implement a `UISlider` in *Cocos2D* which actually works to my surprise.

I've been looking through all the `NSUserDefaults` samples but I can't get anything to work correctly. Just wondered if anyone could help. I think I have the saving of the value correct.

```
- (void) valueChanged:(float) value tag:(int) tag{
    if (tag == 1) // music volume
        [self updateLabel:value];
    [CDAudioManager sharedManager].backgroundMusic.volume = value;

    CCLOG (@"Unknown slider");

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setFloat:value forKey:@"floatKey"];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

It's just reloading the defaults where I'm kind of stuck, I've put this in the initialization of my class. I'm not even sure if it should go there...

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([userDefaults floatForKey:@"floatKey"]) {
    [userDefaults setFloat:value forKey:@"floatKey"];
}
```

Comment: Some people out there ask way more questions in the span of mere minutes :)

Comment: haha i hate to ask questions but it really annoys me when i cant get something to work. This is only my 3rd week working with cocos2d, im slowly learning but its a nightmare haha.

Answer (score 1):

In your initialization, you are *setting* the value for `floatKey` in the prefs instead of getting it. You probably want something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
float value = [userDefaults floatForKey:@"floatKey"]; //read the value from the defaults
[CDAudioManager sharedManager].backgroundMusic.volume = value; //use the value
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, firstly am i saving the volume value correctly in the first piece of code? Ive tried your code just and it throws out an error " local declaration of 'userDefaults' hides instance variable" I hope im not being thick here :)

Comment: Do you already have an instance variable called `value`? If so, just rename the variable in my code fragment. Apart from this, your saving part is fine.

Comment: Yeh i founnd that i had to change that, its still not correct though. Would you mind just having at a look at my settings page.  ` CCSlider *musicVolumeSlider = [[[CCSlider alloc] init] autorelease];
  musicVolumeSlider.position = CGPointMake(90, 70);
  musicVolumeSlider.value = 0;
  musicVolumeSlider.delegate = self;
  [self addChild:musicVolumeSlider z:0 tag:1];
`

Comment: I do not see where you set the slider's value again after retrieving it from the userDefaults.

Comment: ok this is where i set the value, i didnt realise i needed something in here :(                                               `- (void) setValue:(float) newValue
{
 if (newValue < 0) newValue = 0;
 if (newValue > 1.0) newValue = 1.0;
 value = newValue;
 CCSprite *thumb = (CCSprite *)[[self children] objectAtIndex:1];
 CGPoint pos = thumb.position;
 pos.x = minX + newValue * (maxX - minX);
 thumb.position = pos;
 
}`